# How to Filter Nested Array Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, axios, lodash

so I tried to sort data from 2 array objects,

I have tried using Loadash to match the same ID between the two, but the results I want remain empty

```
Array A

    {
      "account": {
        "_id": "5d1efe79dedfe54a984f27f7",
        "status": "not verified",
        "email": "garp@garp.com",
        "name": "garp",
        "phone": "12345",
        "business_id": [
          {
            "role_capability": "all_access",
            "current_active": true,
            "_id": "5d1efe89dedfe54a984f27f9",
            "date_created": "1562309081438",
            "name": "balsem",
            "status": "no verify",
            "desc": "perusahaan balsem untuk nyeri otot"
          },
          {
            "role_capability": "all_access",
            "current_active": false,
            "_id": "5d1efe9adedfe54a984f27fb",
            "date_created": "1562309081438",
            "name": "pulpen",
            "status": "no verify",
            "desc": "pulpen adalah alat untuk nulis"
          },
          {
            "role_capability": "all_access",
            "current_active": false,
            "_id": "5d1efeacdedfe54a984f27fd",
            "date_created": "1562309081438",
            "name": "kaca mobil",
            "status": "no verify",
            "desc": "perusahaan yang bergerak di bidang kaca mobil"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Array B

```
    [
      {
        "_id": "5d1eebb0e3864b452044590a",
        "address": "",
        "status": "no verify",
        "email": "qwe@qwe.com",
        "name": "qwe",
        "phone": "2123123",
        "business_id": [
          {
            "_id": "5d1eebbde3864b452044590c",
            "role_capability": "all_access"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5d1ef967dedfe54a984f27ee",
            "role_capability": "all_access"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": "5d1efe20dedfe54a984f27f1",
        "address": "",
        "status": "not verified",
        "email": "bart@bart.com",
        "name": "Bartolomew",
        "phone": "12344",
        "business_id": [
          {
            "_id": "5d1efe4fdedfe54a984f27f3",
            "role_capability": "all_access"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5d1efe5ddedfe54a984f27f5",
            "role_capability": "all_access"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": "5d1efe79dedfe54a984f27f7",
        "address": "",
        "status": "not verified",
        "email": "garp@garp.com",
        "name": "garp",
        "phone": "12345",
        "business_id": [
          {
            "_id": "5d1efe89dedfe54a984f27f9",
            "role_capability": "all_access"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5d1efe9adedfe54a984f27fb",
            "role_capability": "all_access"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5d1efeacdedfe54a984f27fd",
            "role_capability": "all_access"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": "5d1efecededfe54a984f27ff",
        "address": "",
        "status": "not verified",
        "email": "kizaru@kizaru.com",
        "name": "kizaru",
        "phone": "12345",
        "business_id": [
          {
            "_id": "5d1efedededfe54a984f2801",
            "role_capability": "all_access"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5d1efef6dedfe54a984f2803",
            "role_capability": "all_access"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Here's how I use it

```
    let respFilter
    //first I sort the current_active data which is true
    const busActive = _.filter(cookieActive, function(o) {return  o.current_active === true; });

    //Response data from axios / Array B
    _.forEach(response.data, data => {
    // Then i looping Array B to get an _id and filter with Array A
    respFilter = _.filter(data, response.data[data] === busActive[0]._id)
    })
    //But i still get empty data
    console.log('respoFIlt', respFilter)

result that i want:

    {
        "_id": "5d1efe79dedfe54a984f27f7",
        "address": "",
        "status": "not verified",
        "email": "garp@garp.com",
        "name": "garp",
        "phone": "12345",
        "business_id": [
          {
            "_id": "5d1efe89dedfe54a984f27f9",
            "role_capability": "all_access"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5d1efe9adedfe54a984f27fb",
            "role_capability": "all_access"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5d1efeacdedfe54a984f27fd",
            "role_capability": "all_access"
          }
        ]
      },
```

How do I justify this? and what's wrong with my steps above. sorry if there is a word wrong I use google translate for this

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `find` the item with the correct `_id` in the second array:

```js
const obj = {"account":{"_id":"5d1efe79dedfe54a984f27f7","status":"not verified","email":"garp@garp.com","name":"garp","phone":"12345","business_id":[{"role_capability":"all_access","current_active":true,"_id":"5d1efe89dedfe54a984f27f9","date_created":"1562309081438","name":"balsem","status":"no verify","desc":"perusahaan balsem untuk nyeri otot"},{"role_capability":"all_access","current_active":false,"_id":"5d1efe9adedfe54a984f27fb","date_created":"1562309081438","name":"pulpen","status":"no verify","desc":"pulpen adalah alat untuk nulis"},{"role_capability":"all_access","current_active":false,"_id":"5d1efeacdedfe54a984f27fd","date_created":"1562309081438","name":"kaca mobil","status":"no verify","desc":"perusahaan yang bergerak di bidang kaca mobil"}]}};
const arr = [{"_id":"5d1eebb0e3864b452044590a","address":"","status":"no verify","email":"qwe@qwe.com","name":"qwe","phone":"2123123","business_id":[{"_id":"5d1eebbde3864b452044590c","role_capability":"all_access"},{"_id":"5d1ef967dedfe54a984f27ee","role_capability":"all_access"}]},{"_id":"5d1efe20dedfe54a984f27f1","address":"","status":"not verified","email":"bart@bart.com","name":"Bartolomew","phone":"12344","business_id":[{"_id":"5d1efe4fdedfe54a984f27f3","role_capability":"all_access"},{"_id":"5d1efe5ddedfe54a984f27f5","role_capability":"all_access"}]},{"_id":"5d1efe79dedfe54a984f27f7","address":"","status":"not verified","email":"garp@garp.com","name":"garp","phone":"12345","business_id":[{"_id":"5d1efe89dedfe54a984f27f9","role_capability":"all_access"},{"_id":"5d1efe9adedfe54a984f27fb","role_capability":"all_access"},{"_id":"5d1efeacdedfe54a984f27fd","role_capability":"all_access"}]},{"_id":"5d1efecededfe54a984f27ff","address":"","status":"not verified","email":"kizaru@kizaru.com","name":"kizaru","phone":"12345","business_id":[{"_id":"5d1efedededfe54a984f2801","role_capability":"all_access"},{"_id":"5d1efef6dedfe54a984f2803","role_capability":"all_access"}]}];

const res = arr.find(({ _id }) => _id == obj.account._id);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: This is the answer I'm looking for. thank you, but what if I have 2 arrays how to compare them?